# Controller Test fails with MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException but not in the running application

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Spring Boot App using 2.0.3.RELEASE of Spring Boot.

So I have REST API controller written like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/root/{id}")
@Slf4j
public class RootController {

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<?> getXXX(
      @PathVariable String id,
      @RequestParam(value = "status") Status status, 
      @RequestParam(value = "comment") String comment,       
@RequestParam(value = "other") Optional<String> other) {
    log.info("Requested getXXX id={} status={} other={} comment={}", id, status, other, comment);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
  }

}
```

So the interesting part is the `Optional<String> other` on the above definition. I have tested the above manually via calling curl:

```
curl -v -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/root/ID?status=OK&comment=Comment'
```

which results in logging output on console like this:

```
...Requested getXXX id=ID status=OK other=Optional.empty comment=Comment
```

and using curl like this:

```
curl -v -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/root/ID?status=OK&comment=Comment&other=MoreOther'
```

which results in the following output:

```
Requested getXXX id=ID status=OK other=Optional[MoreOther] comment=Comment
```

So far so good.

But of course I would like to check this via unit tests and not manually...So I wrote a REST controller test which looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RootController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RootControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnNotImplemented() throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    mvc.perform(
        get("/root/xyz?status={status}&comment={comment}&other={other}", Status.NOTOK, "COMMENT", Optional.<String>of("Other"))
          .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
          .accept(MediaType.ALL)
      )
    .andExpect(
          status().isNotImplemented()
        );
    //@formatter:on
  }
```

But unfortunately the above test fails with:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /root/xyz
       Parameters = {status=[OK], comment=[Comment], other=[Optional[Other]]}
          Headers = {Accept=[*/*]}
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = ...RootController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> .getRoot(java.lang.String,Status,java.lang.String,java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Where the exception: `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException` is the thing I don't understand.

The final question is: Why does the test fail but the running application does not? Does someone has a hint / idea for me?

**Update 1:**

I have tested also the following:

```
    get("/root/xyz?status={status}&comment={comment}&other={other}", Status.NOTOK, "COMMENT", "Other")
```

and furthermore which means using only strings.

```
    get("/root/xyz?status={status}&comment={comment}&other={other}", "NOTOK", "COMMENT", "Other")
```

The point that the running application works perfectly but unfortunately the test do not.

**Update 2:**

So after turning on debugging mode in test I got the following output: This brings me more and more into the direction that there is a bug within it..cause the parameters are always converted into String instead of Optional...and based on the parameters of `get(..., Object... uriVars)`
 it looks like there is some problem in the code...

```
2018-07-16 15:50:21.029 DEBUG 16022 --- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /root/xyz
2018-07-16 15:50:21.031 DEBUG 16022 --- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> de....RootController.getXXX(java.lang.String,de....Status,java.lang.String,java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>)]
2018-07-16 15:50:21.057 DEBUG 16022 --- [main] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Failed to resolve argument 3 of type 'java.util.Optional'

org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Optional'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Optional': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:165)
    at de...RootControllerTest.shouldReturnNotImplemented(RootControllerTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Optional': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:52)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:123)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with how you are loading the test up.

When you specify  `@SpringBootTest(classes = RootController.class)` a class with `SpringBootTest` it will *only* load that class into the context i.e. it allows you to specify certain configurations etc. that you would want to test for some integration tests rather than using `ContextConfiguration`.

You can either remove the `RootController` and load a full test application context, effectively loading your entire application.

or just specify,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class RootControllerTest {
```

To load a slice test, which will only load the required beans to completely test the WebMVC.

working tests,

https://github.com/Flaw101/mockmvctests

Edit,

I've updated my example and introduced a second controller but only load the `RootController` in the `RootControllerMock` via `@WebMvcTest(controllers = RootController.class)`. You can see in the logged output that it only load this controller.

`2018-07-16 15:34:28.264  INFO 6176 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/root/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.darrenforsythe.mockmvc.RootController.getXXX(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>)`

references,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests

Comment: The issue with removing `RootController` results in starting up the whole application which I need to prevent cause I want to test my REST API part only nothing else....controller by controller....The whole applications has much more parts which I don't want to mock....At the moment only the mapping for the `Optional<String>...` within the tests seemed to be not working ....

Comment: That is what `WebMvcTest` is for, testing a slice (MVC in this case) of the application, it only loads what is required to test your controller(s). You can even specify the individual controller there if you have more than one within the application. Specifying the `RestController` in a `SpringBootTest` does not mean, load only the `WebMVC` beans + configuration. It means only load this exact class. Optional isn't working as the handlers required to map it isn't being loaded. Use `@WebMvcTest(classes = RestController.class)` this is what is was designed for.

Comment: Hm..maybe I'm mistaken a thing but the handlers for  enums are working ? Apart from that based on the stacktrace it looks like the `MockMvc mvc;` does not handle the Optional conversions correct...in particular `mvc.perform(get("/...", Optional.of("XXX"))`...whereas `mvc.perform(get("/..", Status.Ok)` works?

Comment: Without going under the hood of spring boot it may well be handling the loading of optional differently, the `1.5.x` family does not require Java 8, thus no optional by default it may not know how to load the Optional mapping without extra configurations - although this happens with `2.X` who knows what configs are being triggered to handle it :) . I've also updated my example. I honestly wouldn't worry too much about this as this is how you should be testing your controllers, especially if you want to take advantage of contract tests or rest docs.

Comment: I should add finally that the documentation calls out that the `WebMvcTest` loads the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which is clearly what is missing. I'm not sure what else you are expecting, how you are testing it is wrong given that the application works at runtime

Comment: Hm. Maybe I misunderstand you. I expect that I could write a test for the controller only without starting up the whole application which is exactly what I did. The only issue at the moment is that using of `Optional` in relationship with `@RequestParam` does not work. Within the controller each service/component I can mock as I like to do with this approach. So I can check the basic behaviour of the controller before going more into the depth.. May I misunderstand your comments about contract tests or rest docs...I try to minimise the number of integration tests based on time etc...

Comment: As metnioned the `WebMvcTest` loads a slice of the application, it does not load it all. It is significantly faster than `SpringBootTest`. It only loads a portion of the ApplicationContext related to testing your controllers which is what you are wanting to do